# BeautiulSoup4 Installation issue in VSCode

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-import, importerror

I've BeautifulSoup4 installed in my system but when I import it, I get thrown an error `No module named 'beautifulsoup4'`. I just installed this module as shown in the screenshot [image: screenshot] attached. .

In addition, I've tried the regular pip install method to install BeautifulSoup4 but same issue.

Comment: Try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Before posting, I tried that.  I'm getting error ```multiple exception types must be parenthesized```. @AndrejKesely

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not in the version you installed beautifulSoup4. Try positioning yourself in the python version you intalled it.

Comment: I'm using python version ```3.10.1``` and BeautifulSoup4 is of version ```4.3.2```. BeautifulSoup4 shows up in ```pip list``` too but somehow, it's not getting imported.

Comment: are you working on Visual ?

Comment: Yes.  I'm working on visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the version you are working on with in visual:
[Look for this, and click it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gU0f.png)

you may have two options like so:
[select the one you are not positioned in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sf934.png)

Comment: The other one for me is ```3.9.12```, the base version. I switched to that but unfortunately, same error ```No module named 'beautifulsoup4'```.